# Proving a fundamental group is NOT abelian

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology

I was wondering if the following approach would be possible in proving the fundamental group of $X$ was not abelian.  If one can show there exists a homomorphism: $\pi_1(X, x_0) \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_n * \mathbb{Z}_m$ where $*$ is the free product, then we know that $h([f] * [g]) = h([f]) * h([g]) = x^s*y^t$ for some generators $x$ and $y$.  Likewise, I can write $h([g] * [f]) = h([g]) * h([f]) = y^t*x^s$. Since the free product is not abelian we know that $x^s * y^t \neq y^t*x^s$, so we cannot have $[f]*[g] = [g]*[f]$.  Is this sufficient?

Comment: It looks like you are already assuming this somewhere but you need to know that you are hitting "both parts" of the product. Otherwise as a counterexample map $\mathbb{Z}_n$ into $\mathbb{Z}_n * \mathbb{Z_m}$ by $a \rightarrow a *1$. (To be clear I haven't thought too much about the rest of your argument but I think just showing you have that it is surjective should be enough and your argument would be good)

Comment: Suppose that $h$ is surjective. Then this argument should work?

Comment: Yes see the argument below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is true more generally for surjective maps onto non abelian groups.

Suppose that $h$ is a surjective map from $\pi_1(X,x_0)$ to $G$ and $G$ is non-abelian. Then choose elements $x_1$ and $x_2$ in $G$ such that $x_1 x_2 \not = x_2 x_1$. Now because $h$ is surjective choose $[f]$, $[g]$ such that $h([f])= x_1$ and $h([g])=x_2$ then $h([f*g]) = h([f]) \cdot h([g]) = x_1x_2$ and $h([g*f]) = h([g]) \cdot h([f]) = x_2x_1$. Therefore $h([f*g]) \not = h([g*f])$ and so $[f*g] \not = [g*f]$ and $\pi_1(X,x_0)$ is not abelian.